# Xib file as a Custom TableView Cell crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using **Xib file** as a custom **Tableview Cell**. But everytime i run my application, it crashes. I get this crash logs which i posted below

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:6730
>   2017-12-04 17:23:16.070 iCommander[2489:135476] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035f6b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010305b141 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035facf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000102bf5536 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
>       4   UIKit                               0x00000001042eae45 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 241
>       5   iCommander                          0x0000000101e6b43f _TFC10iCommander25CommentsHistoryController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 303
>       6   iCommander                          0x0000000101e6ba07 _TToFC10iCommander25CommentsHistoryController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 87
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001042fdab2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 750
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001042fdcf8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>       9   UIKit                               0x00000001042d2639 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2845
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000104306ccc -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 111
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001042ede7a -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 233
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010425455b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
>       13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000102429904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010241d526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010241d3a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001023ace92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001023d9130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001023d9b37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010359c717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010359c687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103581720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103581016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
>       23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001091e1a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       24  UIKit                               0x0000000104191134 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       25  iCommander                          0x0000000101e13ea7 main + 55
>       26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010743e65d start + 1
>       27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the crash log? `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: got it. Thanks for the help. Problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to **register the XIB file**. You have to register the xib file for getting rid of the crash.

I**n Swift 3**

```
 let xib = UINib(nibName: "YourCustomCell", bundle: nil)
 tableView.register(xib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

You should register the custom cell like that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man. Solved it. Couldn't upvote you. I am currently not eligible for upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Set cell identifier to custom cell in xib file as:[image: setting cell identifier for reusing cell with that identifier]

Comment: i already use the identifier. I missed one thing which is i didn't register the cell. Btw thanks for your help. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**IN Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XibName", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! XibName

 return cell

    }
```